# Pruning decision tree

Tags: classification, id3, decision-tree, pruning

How to prune decision tree build with ID3 when there are too few examples in the training set.

I cannot divide it into training, validation and test set, so that is out of the question.

Are there any statistical methods that might be used or something like that?

Comment: See the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2314850/help-understanding-cross-validation-and-decision-trees?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes when you have low amounts of data cross-validation can be used to train and prune your dataset.  The idea is fairly simple.  You divide your data into N sets, and train your tree with N-1 of them.  The last set you use as your pruning test set.  Then you pick another set on of the N sets to leave out, and do the same thing.  Repeat this until you've left out all sets.  That means you'll have built N trees.  You'll use these N trees to calculate an optimal size of the tree, then train on the full set of data using the calculation to prune that tree.  It's more complex than I can effectively describe here, but here is an article about how to adapt cross validation to ID3.

[Decision Tree Cross Validation](http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/volume3/blockeel02a/blockeel02a.ps)

Lots of research has been conducted on what the proper segmentation of cross validation, and it's been found N=10 gives the best results for the given extra processing time.  Cross Validation increases your computation time by a lot (well N times), but when you have smaller amounts of data it can overcome the small number of samples.  And since you don't have a lot of data that means using cross validation isn't that bad computationally.